# PHP regex second occurrence

Tags: php, regex

I have some code like below and I am using regex to pull certain content out:

Content

```
[vc_row][vc_column width="1/1"][vc_column_text]
[dt_divider style="thin"/]

size 18" x 18"
[dt_divider style="thin"/]

£70
[/vc_column_text]
```

I have used the following to get the size:

```
preg_match_all("#\[dt_divider.*\](.*)\[dt_#Us", $content, $matches3);
$picsize = $matches3[1][0];

print $picsize;
```

and then tried to get the price using:

```
preg_match_all("#\[dt_divider.*\](.*)\[/vc_#Us", $content, $matches4);
$price = $matches4[1][0];

print $picsize;
```

The above code just arrays out:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [dt_divider style="thin"/] size 18" x 18" [dt_divider style="thin"/] £70[/vc_ ) [1] => Array ( [0] => size 18" x 18" [dt_divider style="thin"/] £70 ))
```

How do I get it to ignore the first `[dt_divider style="thin"/]` so it just picks up the second?

Hope that makes sense :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"#\[dt_divider[^\]]*\]([^\[]*)\[/vc_#Us"
```

Should fix your problem whilst changing your regex as little as possible. Like with your size, the price will be in capture group 1.

The trouble with your regex was that `.*` tries to match as much as it can.

I'm using `[^\]]*` and `[^\]]*` to replace the two `.*`. These say match 0 to many (`*`) characters that are not `]` or `[` (`\]` or `\[`).

[Working Example](http://regexr.com?37d99)

A slightly improved version would be:

```
"#\[dt_divider[^\]]*\]\s*([^\[]*?)\s*\[/vc_#Us"
```

This does exactly the same, but any whitespace (the newlines) around the price will be excluded from the match.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to capture it with `\[dt_divider style="thin"\/\]\s*£([\d\.]+)`

**Match groups:**
[121-123]

`70`

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/^\[dt_divider style=\"thin\"\/\][\n\r]+\s*\K[^\n\r]+/m", $s, $m)
```

See demo **[here](http://ideone.com/psXZck)**.